# Read Table and Random Forest in R

Tags: r, dataset, random-forest

I'm trying to use the Random Forest method in R. I need to read a txt file (training set).

```
dataset<- read.table(path1,header=TRUE,sep=",")
```

The column names are numeric (i.e 1005_at) so they are automatically converted, adding X, by R (i.e X1005_at). In order to resolve this problem I did:

```
colnames(dataset)<-gsub("^[X](.*)","\\1",colnames(dataset))
```

Now the names are ok, but when I run the Random Forest:

```
model.rf <- randomForest(class ~ ., data=dataset, importance=TRUE,keep.forest=T, ntree=5, do.trace=T)
```

I have this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '1005_at' not found
```

While if I run the Random Forest on the original dataset (without modify the names, so using X1005_at) this error doesn't occur. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: I cant say for sure, but I would guess it has to do with the non-standard name of the columns combined with the fact that `randomForest` is evaluating a formula.  I'm sure if you look at the code, that `.` will translate to a substitute statement (or equivalent) somewhere which is likely a list of the **names** of the columns of `dataset`.  The function most likely does not make allotments for non-standard names (no need why it should, since it has expectations of the user) and hence the error

Comment: Why not simply resolve the names as a final step?

Comment: I've come across this issue when using aggregate() on data frames with underscore in the column name. Web search is not bringing up any good explanations so far. But if it works with the converted names - as Ricardo said, why not just use those and fix the names at the end?

Comment: Because I want to save the rules in a text file. So it means I should modify every rules and I have no idea how to do it directly on R (I could do on the text file I generated, but I'd like to avoid this extra step)

Answer (score 0):

Use `read.csv` as it already has the appropriate defaults for `header` and `sep` and use the `check.names=FALSE` argument to avoid mangling the names.

The `formula` method of `randomForest` will not accept non-syntactic names in the input data frame.  Use the default method instead.

Thus we have:

```
> # dataset <- read.csv(path1, check.names = FALSE)
> 
> # next few lines are to make example similar to the one in the question
> dataset <- CO2
> names(dataset) <- c(paste(1:4, names(dataset[1:4]), sep = "_"), "class")
> names(dataset)
[1] "1_Plant"     "2_Type"      "3_Treatment" "4_conc"      "class"      
> 
> i <- match("class", names(dataset)) # i is index of class column
> fm <- randomForest(dataset[-i], dataset[[i]]
+    # other arguments - in this example none
+ )
> fm

Call:
 randomForest(x = dataset[-i], y = dataset[[i]]) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 1

          Mean of squared residuals: 26.43385
                    % Var explained: 77.13
> fm$importance
            IncNodePurity
1_Plant          2105.779
2_Type           1529.527
3_Treatment       557.300
4_conc           2265.724
```

Comment: Using the method randomForest as you suggested:                    model.rf <- randomForest(dataset[-i] , data=dataset[[i]], importance=TRUE,keep.forest=T, ntree=5, do.trace=T)                         it doesn't work. It ends immediately (while with the original parameters it takes few minutes) and the accuracies are not printed.

Comment: I have revised it to provide the complete model.matrix.

Comment: I still have the same error at the end of the RF execution: Error in if (var.class == "character" | var.class == "factor" | var.class ==  : 
  argument is of length zero

Comment: I have made further revisions and shown the output for a test example based on the `CO2` dataset that comes with R.  If the above does not work for you when translated to your data set then you will need to provide your question in reproducible form.

Comment: I'm using the library "Rattle" to print rules from the RandomForest. I've discovered that the error concerns this package. So using your method I can't get the rules, while using the default one (without any reanaming) it works. Thanks anyway for your help!